# Generating QR code sheet with 40 QR codes on A4 sheet, resulting different allignment on different systems

Tags: java, xml, qr-code, xlsx

I'm working on a `Java NetBeans application`, where user can generate sheet of 40 QR codes on a PDF file, for that I'm using `Apache FOP` , For designing/Formatting the QR code PDF , I'm using `xlsx` file ,for dynamic data `xml` file.

Problem is after printing the PDF on A4 sheet, it is giving different allignment from different systems.

Does anyone can tell what could be the issue, as those barcodes are to be printed on Label sheets, as they will be used as stickers, different allignment is causing the QR codes to go outside there assigned area. Alignment should be constant across all systems.

Any help will be appreciated, and any more info I'll provide.

Method for creating PDF file

```
public void createPdfSheet() throws IOException, TransformerException, FOPException, SAXException{        
    addWardNameToXml(wardName_QR);

    File files = new File("pdf");
    if (!files.exists()) {
        if (files.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory is created!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
        }
    }
       String pdfFile = "";

        try {
        System.out.println("FOP ExampleXML2PDF\n");
        System.out.println("Preparing...");
        // Setup input and output files
        File xmlfile = new File("pdf\\", "document.xml");
        File xsltfile = new File("pdf\\", "template.xsl");
        File pdffile = new File("pdf\\", "codeland.pdf");
        OutputStream file;
        try{
            file = new FileOutputStream(new File("pdf\\codeland.pdf"));
            pdfFile = "pdf\\codeland.pdf";
            pdffile = new File("pdf/", "codeland.pdf");
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fof){
            pdfFile = "pdf\\codeland"+new Date().getTime()+".pdf";
            file = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfFile));
            pdffile = new File("pdf/", "codeland"+new Date().getTime()+".pdf");    
        }          

        System.out.println("Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
        System.out.println("Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
        System.out.println("Output: PDF (" + pdffile + ")");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Transforming...");
        // configure fopFactory as desired
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("fop-2.2\\fop\\conf\\fop.xconf"));
        //new File("src/fop.xconf");
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        // configure foUserAgent as desired
        // Setup output
        OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
        out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);
        try {
            // Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,
                    foUserAgent, out);
            // Setup XSLT
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory
                    .newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));
            // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
            transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
            // Setup input for XSLT transformation
            Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);
            // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through
            // to FOP
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
            transformer.transform(src, res);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Success!");

        //pdfFile = "pdf\\codeland.pdf";
        file.close();
        File fileForDesktop = new File(pdfFile);
        if (pdfFile.toString().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + pdfFile);
        } else {
           //For cross platform use
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.open(fileForDesktop);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("ERROR!!");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

xlsx file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                page-height="11.69in" page-width="8.27in" margin-top="0.0in"
                margin-bottom="0.0in" margin-left="0.0in" margin-right="0.0in">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="0cm" margin-bottom="0cm" />
                <fo:region-before extent="0cm" overflow="hidden" />
                <fo:region-after extent="0cm" overflow="hidden" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple"
            initial-page-number="1">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block font-size="0.0pt" font-family="serif"
                    padding-after="0.0pt" space-before="0.0pt" text-align="center"
                    border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.0pt">
                    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block font-size="0.0pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                    padding-after="0.0pt" space-before="0.0pt" text-align="center"
                    border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.0pt">
                    <xsl:text>P</xsl:text>
                    <fo:page-number />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="data" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data">
    <fo:block text-align="center">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
            <fo:table-column column-width="20%" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="20%" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="20%" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="20%" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="20%" />

            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" height="1.4in">
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in" padding-bottom="0.05in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR1.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                                             
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                             
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block> 
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR2.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                     
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>         
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR3.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                         
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>         
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR4.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                     
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>         
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR5.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                     
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>         
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>     
                <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" height="1.4in">
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR36.png)" />
                        </fo:block> 
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                         
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR37.png)" />
                        </fo:block> 
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>     
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR38.png)" />
                        </fo:block>     
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>     
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR39.png)" />
                        </fo:block>     
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>     
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell height="1.03in">
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align="center" >
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="hospital" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="auto" width="auto" content-height="1.03in"
                                                    content-width="1.03in" src="url(file:pdf/QR40.png)" />  
                        </fo:block>     
                        <fo:block  font-size="7pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                                background-color="white" color="black" text-align-last="center" >                                       
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="floor" />
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
                            <fo:external-graphic  height="0.1in" width="0.1in" content-height="0.1in"
                                                    content-width="0.1in" src="url(file:pdf/dot.png)" />
                        </fo:block>                                                 
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>             
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no question here, is it something like "How can I make them align identically across all systems?"

Comment: @JussiV Yes, I thought it was implicit.

Comment: It sort of is, but someone already downvoted your question, maybe it was because of that. Or because of lack of code sample, who knows.

Comment: the question looks like it is about generating QR-codes in FOP which is absolutely not the case. It is about aligning png-images